# How to dynamically register GraniteDS remote destinations with Spring?

Tags: apache-flex, spring-mvc, graniteds

I'm trying to make Spring automatically register my remote destinations by reading its annotations. So that I don't need to update some configuration file every time I create a new service.

I got it almost working after reading the graniteds-spring documentation:

http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/2.+Spring+Services

But I still need to add a:

`<graniteds:remote-destination name="myService" source="myService" />` to every service bean for it to work.

@RemoteDestination is present but is been ignored. The same goes for `<granite-config scan="true">` and the empty services-config.properties.

Am I missing a jar? I can never get them right, never know which ones to use. (Java's greatest problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is old, but I'll leave an answer if anyone need that...

In addition to add @RemoteDestination annotation, you need:

1. add graniteDS listener on web.xml:

   < listener>
   < listener-class>org.granite.config.GraniteConfigListener< /listener-class>
   < /listener>
2. Create this empty properties file: /META-INF/services-config.properties
   This file needs to be on the project(jar) that you want to be scaned by graniteDS.

More info:
http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.spring.html#spring.roscan